# remove HttpClientModule from my custom library

Tags: angular

My interceptors are not working and finally narrowed the problem because HttpClientModule. Currently, it is compiled to my dist folder and imported as any module. Now in my main app, I import HttpClientModule but my interceptor is not working : it resets and no header is added to outgoing requests. According to this [git issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575), libraries shouldn't import the module and instead make use of the one imported in the AppModule.

Removing the HttpClientModule from library does compile to dist folder and my app works. But testing the library itself and modules that make use of the library fail with the error

```
No provider for HttpClient!
```

The stack trace goes to my library.

How do I go about to make my library work

Comment: Import HttpClienttestingModule from the testing module used in your tests (i.e. TestBed.configureTestingModule()).

Comment: Did you try using HttpClient for sending request?
Do you have some code that you can share?